# WSO2 pizzashack does not build (maven dependency)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have downloaded the last version of WSO2 API manager and try to run the tutorial.

When trying to build the PizzaShack sample with maven, I get this error

> Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/httpcomponents/wso2/httpclient/4.1.1-wso2v1/httpclient-4.1.1-wso2v1.pom
>
> ---
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ---
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pizza-shack-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.pizzashack.client.web:pizza-shack-web:war:1.0.0:
>
> Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.httpcomponents.wso2:httpclient:jar:4.1.1-wso2v1:
>
> Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.httpcomponents.wso2:httpclient:jar:4.1.1-wso2v1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.httpcomponents.wso2:httpclient:pom:4.1.1-wso2v1 from/to wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/): maven.wso2.org: Unknown host maven.wso2.org -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Error says `Unknown host maven.wso2.org`

Make sure your computer has access to `maven.wso2.org`